# Why can't I pull a "Related()" column from another table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have two tables:

**Email Jobs:** has several columns on email jobs such as a `Send ID` and `Sent Time`

**Send ID:** a unique list of all `Send ID`'s coming from the "Email Jobs" table

I'm trying to pull the `Sent Time` column from the "Email Jobs" table into the "Send ID" table but the following function doesn't register the column (the column and table name show up in light grey)[image: Formula]
[image: Relationship]
[image: Relationship Conditions]
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is would help you [**The column either doesn’t exist or doesn’t have a relationship to any table available in the current context.**](https://devoworx.net/power-bi-related-vs-lookupvalue-dax/)

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to use `RELATED` function directly only if it is a "one to one relationship". If it is a "many to one" relationship, then you might have multiple values for the same record. In this case you will have to use `RELATEDTABLE` function and aggregate the values. The following link explains the basics of this function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/relatedtable-function-dax

The following calculation might work in your scenario:

```
Calc = MAXX(RELATEDTABLE('Id Send Jobs'),[SentTime])
```

Hope this helps.